# Resolve Laravel Passport 2.0 installation Error

Tags: php, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

I had using laravel 5.3 previously, but now I just upgraded to laravel 5.4, Now I try to configure Laravel passport but I got following problems,

Problem 1 :

```
- laravel/passport v1.0.1 requires symfony/psr-http-message-bridge ^0.3.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/psr-http-message-bridge[v0.3].
- laravel/passport v1.0.2 requires symfony/psr-http-message-bridge ^0.3.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/psr-http-message-bridge[v0.3].
- laravel/passport v1.0.3 requires symfony/psr-http-message-bridge ^0.3.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/psr-http-message-bridge[v0.3].
- laravel/passport v1.0.4 requires symfony/psr-http-message-bridge ^0.3.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/psr-http-message-bridge[v0.3].
- laravel/passport v1.0.5 requires symfony/psr-http-message-bridge ^0.3.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/psr-http-message-bridge[v0.3].
- laravel/passport v1.0.6 requires symfony/psr-http-message-bridge ^0.3.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/psr-http-message-bridge[v0.3].
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/psr-http-message-bridge v0.3
- Can only install one of: symfony/psr-http-message-bridge[v0.2, v0.4].
- Can only install one of: symfony/psr-http-message-bridge[v0.4, v0.2].
- Can only install one of: symfony/psr-http-message-bridge[v0.2, v0.4].
- laravel/passport v1.0.0 requires symfony/psr-http-message-bridge ^0.2.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/psr-http-message-bridge[v0.2].
- Installation request for laravel/passport ^1.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/passport[v1.0.0, v1.0.1, v1.0.2, v1.0.3, v1.0.4, v1.0.5, v1.0.6].
- Installation request for symfony/psr-http-message-bridge (locked at v0.4) -> satisfiable by symfony/psr-http-message-bridge[v0.4].
```

Can any one help me how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

try `composer require symfony/psr-http-message-bridge` and also after that `composer update`,

Comment: check version of  symfony/psr-http-message-bridge in your composer.json file

Comment: like this - laravel/passport v1.0.0 requires symfony/psr-http-message-bridge ^0.2.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/psr-http-message-bridge[v0.2] but these conflict with
 your requirements or minimum-stability.

Answer (score 0):

Change this lines on your `composer.json`:

```
  "laravel/passport": "^5.0.0",
  "symfony/psr-http-message-bridge": "^1.0.2",
  "zendframework/zend-diactoros:": "^1.0.2",
```

`laravel/passport` 1.x its a little old version (year 2016).